# Android: Can we load listview with ArrayList of objects without using BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView and it should be populated with ArrayList of objects.

```
ArrayList<BrowserClass> playListArr = new ArrayList<BrowserClass>();
```

and here is BrowserClass:

```
public class BrowserClass{
    String musicName = null;
    int musicId = 0;

    BrowserClass(String Name, int Id)
    {
        musicName = Name;
        musicId = Id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return musicName;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return musicId;
    }

}
```

In order to populate ListView I am using following code:

```
ArrayAdapter<BrowserClass> plAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BrowserClass>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, playListArr);
myListView.setAdapter(plAdapter);
```

But the listView is showing some garbage value. I need to display only the names(getname() in browser class). I can achieve this using Custom Listview, BaseAdapter. But i want to implement it without using BaseAdapter.

Comment: I think,you need to have adapter for this. It can be anything like BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this :

**Product.java**

```
public class Product {
private int id;
private String name;
private double price;

public Product(){
    super();
}

public Product(int id, String name, double price) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.id + ". " + this.name + " [$" + this.price + "]";
}
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Product[] items = { 
        new Product(1, "Milk", 21.50), 
        new Product(2, "Butter", 15.99), 
        new Product(3, "Yogurt", 14.90), 
        new Product(4, "Toothpaste", 7.99), 
        new Product(5, "Ice Cream", 10.00), 
    };

    ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: [this link](http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/)  is one good example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Overriding the toString() worked perfectly for me.

Comment: but if you want get BrowserClass.id from every items of list the example is a good way.

Comment: But i dont understand why it is working. I have used ArrayAdapter<BrowserClass>. How does the overriding of toString() worked here if I used BrowserClass object in ArrayAdapter.

Comment: casting every object to string calls the method tostring.

Comment: myListView.setAdapter(plAdapter); cast every items of arrayAdapter to string.

Comment: I got it. So by default it displays the classname and object hashcode. Overriding toString() helps us to display user wanted result. Thanks

Comment: try example in link i camment. by this way you can use custom layout for list item(use images,...).

Comment: I know how to do it by custom layout for list item. My question itself says i just want to implement it without using custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the adapter to work as is, you should override the toString() method in the BrowserClass class. The adapter will use it to fill the list view, and the default toString() method uses the memory location of your object.

The [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) Method is a generic method which exist in all Java Objects. The default behavior of an ArrayAdapter is to display the objects in one line of texts. The generic way to convert an object to text is the toString Method. By default this returns something like this "MyClass@0x1D2EF5512" (the class name and location of the object in memory).

When overriding the toString() method, you tell java how your object is to be displayed as a string.

Comment: It worked fine. But i dont know why it is working. I have used ArrayAdapter<BrowserClass>. How does the overriding of toString() worked here if I used BrowserClass object in ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `ArrayList` for adapter constructor. First you need to copy ArrayList items  to array then pass this new created array to Adapter constructor.

How  You Copy ArrayList Items to Array

```
ArrayList.toArray(Array);
```

then used  Array  for adapter constructor.

Hope you understand what i want to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a simple list:

```
Class File:

    public class Name{
        public Integer id;
        public String text;

        public Name() {
        }

        public Name(int id, String text) {
            this.id = id;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String toString() 
        {
            return this.text;
        }
    }


Activity File:


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        editsearch = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search1);

        editsearch.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        List<Name> list = new List<Name>();
        list.add(new Name(1, "a1"));
        list.add(new Name(2, "a2"));
        list.add(new Name(3, "a3"));


        ArrayAdapter<Name> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Name>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list );

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```